# Error al tratar de traer imagenes de una Api

Tags: flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la api de donde quiero traer las imagenes. copie esa url en la parte de la peticion y al tratar de renderizarlas en pantalla me dice que esperaba un string pero encontro un list dinamic.
intente con un tostring() pero la verdad no se.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Api extends StatefulWidget {
  var url = Uri.parse("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images");

  Future<dynamic> getdogs() async {
    final respuesta = await http.get(url);

    if (respuesta.statusCode == 200) {
      //print(jsonDecode(respuesta.body));
      return (jsonDecode(respuesta.body));
    } else {
      print("Error con la respusta");
    }
  }

  //Api({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Api> createState() => _ApiState();
}

class _ApiState extends State<Api> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: widget.getdogs(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Image.network(snapshot.data["message"]
                  ),
                  //Text("${snapshot.data["status"]}"),
                ],
              );
              
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El message de error es correcto, `snapshot.data["message"]` te da un listado de objetos "dynamic", es decir maps, y tu estás pasándole eso a `Image.network` que espera solo un String con la URL.

Prueba con

```dart
 Image.network(snapshot.data["message"].first),
 //o
 Image.network(snapshot.data["message"][0]),
```

Y te va a funcionar, mostrándote la primera imagen, ahora, si quieres mostrar un Listado de imágenes necesitas usar un `ListView`.

Más info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: usted como siempre don diego ayudando gracias. sin embargo replantie la pregunta en su grupo porque es cierto no le puedo pasar un listado de objetos a un widget que espera una url. intente creando un arreglo para almacenar esos objetos y luego recorrerlo pero no imposible.

Comment: final lista = (snapshot.data["message"] as List) ;    aquí ya tienes la lista, ahora solo recorre y usa un listview.builder

Comment: tuve que lanzar otra amigo :)

Comment: @mauricio podrás marcar esta pregunta como resuelta?

Comment: de hecho resuelve 1 solo problema no todo. pero si claro la marque como resuelta

Comment: @mauricio aún sigue abierta, el icono ^ no la deja resuelta, solo es un voto a favor.